# Copy IP and use in Applescript

Tags: applescript, autohotkey, keyboard-maestro

I am using Keyboard Maestro and within that using applescript for following action:

- Copy IP address from anywhere
- Open terminal
- Use copied IP into applescript
- ssh on IP which was copied from somewhere

  ```
  tell application "Terminal"
  activate
  do script "ssh & the clipboard" -- this always opens a new window
  ```

  end tell

Kindly help me with the solution on how I can use "copied" text within applescript to do ssh, as I dont want to write direct IP within script

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I want to automate SSH command. Copy IP address, press Keycombination (Control+Shift+T on mac) and it should open terminal, type ssh user@copied_ip and password. Previously I was using AutoHot key which does this but AutoHot key doesnt work on MAC, so looking for alternatives

Comment: It's still unclear what you are asking. What does *fixing this* mean?

Comment: I have edited the post.. and now looking for help in solution - not fixing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok got the answer

```
set ipaddress to the clipboard  tell application "Terminal"     
activate     
do script "ssh " & ipaddress & " " -- this always opens a
new window end tell
```